# How to iterate over JSON Object and get the values for each key

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have a JSONObject which had a JSONArray as a value for each key.

```
{
    "abc" : [null, "1,3", "2,4"],
    "dbs" : [null, "1,4", "4,5"],
    "sad" : [null, "6,2", "3,4", "5,5"]
}
```

I want to iterate over the object and take the JSONArray value for each key and put it into a string[]. Example for key: abc i would like to have a String[]: `[null, "1,3", "2,4"]`

Could some one please help me with this?

I have tried the following:

```
for (var key in jsonObject) {
    if (jsonObject.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
        var array = jsonObject[key];
    }
}
```

But this gives me: ",1,3,2,4"

Comment: this does not work as it just gives me ",1,2". which totally defeats the purpose

Comment: Can you show us what you've tried?

Comment: And the string needs the name of the key or? like: `var abc = [1, 2];`?

Comment: @Maarten: The new string [] can be of any name.

Comment: do you need to filter out null values?

Comment: no i don;t want to filter out anything. I want the array as is.

Comment: @Sunny `i would like to have a String[]: ["1", "2"]` - you really need to be explicit in your question. That is not what you are asking at all. The array "as-is" would be `[null, "1", "2"]`

Comment: @sorry my bad. let me edit the question

Comment: @RGraham: ok i have edited the question and made it clear. Could you please help me?

Comment: Ok thanks for clarification, please allowed me few minutes so I will edit my answer thanks!

Comment: ok thanks. i shall wait

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
function extract(data){
    return Object.keys(data).map(function(x){
        return data[x].filter(function(z){return z!==null;});
    });
}
```

Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yn2wn7hL/) to play with. For explanation of map, take a look at [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

If you want to flatten the data, you could extend it to:

```
function flatten(data){
  return Object.keys(Object.keys(data).map(function(x){
    return data[x].filter(function(z){return z!==null;});
  }).reduce(function(o,n){
    n.forEach(function(x){
      o[x]=x;
    });
    return o;
  },{}));
}
```

Comment: how do i get the fiddle to work. i click on run and nothing hapens

Comment: Open the dev-tools of your browser ;) e.g. F12 should work on all common browsers

Comment: btw how is this solution different from what i did? Sorry i am a noobie

Comment: Your initial code doesn't work. Here is an update of your code, making it work: http://jsfiddle.net/yn2wn7hL/1/ but the filtering of "null"-elements is still missing. Here with filter: http://jsfiddle.net/yn2wn7hL/2/